# interior of a level set

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $F(z):\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $F(z)=l$ is a level set that we can show is a Jordan curve in the complex plane (or $R^2$). Under what condition on $F(z)$, we can say that $F(z)<l$ is located in the interior of $F(z)=l$ and $F(z)>l$ is located in the interior of $F(z)=l$?

Comment: Since you did it systematically, let me tell you that the most common spelling in English is *interior* and *exterior*. The second vowel is an *e* instead of an *o*.

Answer (score 1):

the simple condition that does this is that the Hessian matrix of the function (of two real variables) is positive definite.

After that, one may allow that there is a global diffeomorphism that carries $F$ to a convex function.

Comment: I wanted to see if we can invoke something like "a simple closed curve is  homeomorphic to a unit circle".

Comment: If we are able to show that the level set is a simple closed curve, wouldn't it be enough to say that the interior is either F(z)<l or F( z)>l? Is there a way to avoid computing Hessian and use geometric observation? Also is it possible for you to explain your solution via a numerical example.

Answer (score 0):

I'll only consider the zero level set so "positive" and "negative" make sense. It's enough if $F$ is continuous, the interior and exterior of the zero level set are path connected sets, and there are two points $x_I$ in the interior and $x_O$ in the exterior where $F$ takes opposite sign. Then for any $x$ in the interior, there is a curve from $x$ to $x_I$ in the interior of the level set (i.e. $F$ is never zero), so by the intermediate value theorem, $x$ has the same sign as $x_I$. Likewise, any point outside the zero level set has the same sign as $x_O$.